# How can I check the status of the first program in pipeline in Perl's system()?

Tags: perl, ipc

```
perl -e 'system ("crontab1 -l");print $?'
```

returns -1 as expected (program crontab1 doesn't exist)

```
perl -e 'system ("crontab1 -l|grep blah");print $?'
```

returns 256.

What is the way to check the status of the first (or both) programs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the exit status of the entire command, just as you should. If you want the exit status separately, you're going to have to run the commands separately.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -e
system("crontab1 -l > /tmp/junk.txt"); print $?;
system("grep blah /tmp/junk.txt"); print $?;
```

as an example.

Comment: @Michael Kohne, by "output" do you mean "termination status"?  The OP doesn't want to differentiate his subprocesses' *output*, but their exit statuses.

Comment: This is helpful, but now I would need an error handling for a file access.
For example this:
    perl -e 'system("crontab1 -l > /blah"); print $?;' 
still gives me 256. 
I guess I would need to split it further :)

Comment: No need for a temp file. JB has a better answer below.

Answer (score 4):

If you tolerate using something other than `system`, there are easier solutions.  For example, [the `results` method in IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/dist/IPC-Run/lib/IPC/Run.pm#results) returns all exit codes of the chain.

Comment: I'm sure IPC::Run is great, but back when I was looking for something similar I found Proc::SafeExec first. It worked great, though seems a little more verbose then IPC::Run. It's nice to have options :-)

Comment: Good info, thanks, but IPC is currently not a part of the project, prefer not to introduce new dependency at this time.

Comment: @vt: you can accomplish something similar with open(..., "-|", ...) or open(..., "|-", ...) (fork with STDIN/STDOUT attached between child processes), and exec(...), but IPC::Run or Proc::SafeExec is so much easier to use. I'd get over your preference if I were you, rather than using a temp file (which is another type of dependency). I have some code here: perlmonks.org/?node_id=246397

Answer (score 3):

Remember, you're supposed to use $?>>8 to get the exit code, not $?

```
perl -e 'system("set -o pipefail;false | true");print $?>>8,"\n"'
```

1

This ("pipefail") only works if your shell is bash 3.  Cygwin and some Linux flavors  ship with it; not sure about mac.

You should be aware that 256 is an error return.  0 is what you'd get on success:

```
perl -e 'system("true");print $?>>8,"\n"'
```

0

I didn't know system returned -1 for a single command that isn't found, but $?>>8 should still be non-zero in that case.

Comment: You should really be using POSIX::WEXITSTATUS instead of right shifting

Comment: Even with the right shifting it's still not a -1 I was looking for.

Comment: 255 is the -1 you are looking for, as `((int)-1 & 0377)` (which is what `exit()` transforms the return to) is `0xff`, or 255

Answer (score 2):

[*This was composed as an answer to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28413618/589924) which was closed as a duplicate of this one.*]

Executing a shell command requires executing a shell. To that end,

```
system($shell_command)
```

is equivalent to

```
system('/bin/sh', '-c', $shell_command)
```

As such, all of your examples run a single program (`/bin/sh`). If you want the exit statuses of multiple children, you're going to need to have multiple children!

```
use IPC::Open3 qw( open3 );

open(local *CHILD1_STDIN, '<', '/dev/null')
   or die $!;

pipe(local *CHILD2_STDIN, local *CHILD1_STDOUT)
   or die $!;

my $child1_pid = open3(
   '<&CHILD1_STDIN',
   '>&CHILD1_STDOUT',
   '>&STDERR',
   'prog1', 'arg1', 'arg2',
);

my $child2_pid = open3(
   '<&CHILD2_STDIN',
   '>&STDOUT',
   '>&STDERR',
   'prog2', 'arg1', 'arg2',
);

my @pipe_status = map { waitpid($_, 0) } $child1_pid, $child2_pid;
```

IPC::Open3 is rather low level. IPC::Run3 and/or IPC::Run can possibly make this easier. [Update: Indeed, IPC::Run [does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1331538/589924)].

Comment: @Wakan Tanka, This answer was written in response to your question.

Comment: Thank you but I am a little bit confused with syntax. E.g. you are using `open3` function from `IPC::Open3` module but in code you are using classic `open` function.

Comment: @Wakan Tanka, `open` is indeed used, but so is `open3`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check the status, don't put them all in the same system. Open a reading pipe to the first program to get its output then open another pipe to the other program.

Answer (score 1):

The operating system returns an exit status only for the last program executed and if the OS doesn't return it, perl can't report it.

I don't know of any way to get at the exit code returned by earlier programs in a pipeline other than by running each individually and using temporary files instead of pipes.

Answer (score 1):

> *What is the way to check the status of the first (or both) programs?*

There is no such way, at least, not as you have constructed things.  You may have to manage sub-processes yourself via fork(), exec() and waitpid() if you must know these things.

Here is roughly what is happening in your code fragment.

1. `perl`'s *system()* spawns a shell, and `perl` *wait()*s for that subprocess to terminate.
2. The shell sets up a pipeline:

   1. a subshell *exec()*s `grep` on the read-end of the pipe
   2. a subshell fails to locate `crontab1` anywhere in `$PATH`, and *exit()*s 127 (on my system, that is, where 127 is the shell indicating failure to find a program to run).
3. `grep` detects end-of-file on its input and, having matched nothing, *exit()*s 1.
4. The shell *exit()*s with the exit code of the last process in the pipeline, which, again, is 1.
5. `perl` detects the shell's exit code of 1, which is encoded in `$?` as 256.

   (256 >> 8 == 1)